# Error when trying to upload to database

Tags: java, android

Hey guys im trying to insert some data into a database from an android app, but the app crashes when trying to do so, i have the error log, but cant quite seem to figure out what it does. Can anyone please help me?

This is the error log: `https://pastebin.com/Z8HmE21T`
This is the code: `https://pastebin.com/pCWaFniC`

And this is my json parser

```js
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
   List<NameValuePair> params) {

  // Making HTTP request
  try {
   
   // check for request method
   if(method == "POST"){
    // request method is POST
    // defaultHttpClient
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    is = httpEntity.getContent();
    
   }else if(method == "GET"){
    // request method is GET
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
    url += "?" + paramString;
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    is = httpEntity.getContent();
   }   
   

  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  try {
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
     is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   String line = null;
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line + "\n");
   }
   is.close();
   json = sb.toString();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
  }

  // try parse the string to a JSON object
  try {
   jObj = new JSONObject(json);
  } catch (JSONException e) {
   Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
  }

  // return JSON String
  return jObj;
```

Comment: `but the app crashes` can you show the stacktrace?

Comment: @PeterSamokhin im not quite sure what that is, im new to this

Comment: Do you know how to see app's logs? I.e. output of yours `Log.e(TAG, string)`? Do you ever heard about logcat?

Comment: @PeterSamokhin if stacktrace is the functions executed up untill the point of the app crash, then this is my stracktrace https://pastebin.com/ArnVYZPS

Comment: It is saying that your `json` is null

Comment: @ScaryWombat i can see that. But why?

Comment: Well you are trying to read this inputstream `is = httpEntity.getContent();` but I am not sure what you expect to be there for a GET.  Basically you will need to debug your code and find out what is happening.